# Existe alguma forma de mostrar meu projeto local na internet sem colocá-lo em uma hospedagem?

Tags: hospedagem, atualização

Várias vezes preciso apresentar a um cliente um projeto que estou trabalhando localmente e é ruim ter que subir o projeto para uma hospedagem ou mesmo atualizar o projeto toda vez que o cliente pedir para ver como está indo o trabalho.

Existe alguma forma, *real time*, que consiga compartilhar meu trabalho local na internet sem esforço?

Comment: Cuidados com essas perguntas que ficam próximas de só você poder responder corretamente. Não tem problema dar a resposta mas a pergunta precisa dar a chance de outras pessoas responderem bem. Quando vai responder sua própria pergunta certifique-se que ela está bem feita para que todos compreendam ela e que ela não seja viável apenas lendo sua própria resposta junto.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Eu entendo sua preocupação, mas neste caso quis compartilhar meu conhecimento e achei valido postar aqui sobre a ferramenta ngrok, que é muito util para muitas pessoas.

Comment: A ideia do *site* não é ficar divulgando ferramentas. Corre o risco de ter sinalização de *spam*.

Comment: Eu entendo, irei tomar mais cuidado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução excelente para este problema é o [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), esta ferramenta cria um túnel entre seu projeto local e a internet disponibilizando uma URL para acesso. É altamente configurável e fácil de usar. Você ainda pode acompanhar quantos acessos tem em sua app, a transferencia sendo feita entre a conexão, etc...